# How to select the selected option field in dropdown in php

Tags: php, drop-down-menu, html-select, selected

Consider the following command:

```
echo '<option value="', $row['name'], '">', $row['name'], '</option>';
```

Now how do I add the following code into the code I'm doing does not work either.

```
if ($row['name'] =='class2' )echo " selected ";
```

Comment: I'm afraid we need more info, and the context of what you're doing and what you want to do. More code maybe.

Comment: please post some extended code, not the part you suppose to be wrong... and explain what is not working, provide error messages, etc ...

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
if ($row['name'] =='class2' ){echo "selected=\"selected\"";}
```

edit: I hope I got your point right with that less informations...

just to put it right for you:

```
<select>
<option 
<?
if ($row['name'] =='class2' )
{echo "selected=\"selected\"";}
?> value="<?=$row[name]?>">
<?=$row[name]?>
</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this ?

```
<option <?php echo $row['name']=='class2'?"selected='selected'":""; ?> 
    value="<?php echo $row['name'] ?>">
    <?php echo $row['name'] ?>
</option>
```